# Variable changed in parent but is not changed in child VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try to change a Boolean variable `isSubmited` after a post request is made from parent component, and this will trigger a watch from child and there will be another post request that uses the ID form first response.

The flow begins from parent component.

1. User click on submit
2. In parent I create a new contract and I receive an ID from response (after post request is made)
3. After post request, I change a Boolean value ,to activate a watch from child.
4. In child component I will do another post that uses the ID form parent response

Basically 2 post request, first in parent and the second one in child that uses the ID from parent.

**From parent component**

```
 <upload-file-test :id_contract="id_contract" :isSubmited="isSubmited" ></upload-file-test>

     addContract(data) {
           this.isSubmited = !this.isSubmited;  //from here in child component watch it works

           post("/url", data)
               .then((response) => {
                   this.id_contract = response.data;
                   this.isSubmited = !this.isSubmited;  //from here in child component is not changed
                }
    }
```

**From child component**

```
props: ['id_contract', 'isSubmited']

 watch:{
        isSubmited: {
            handler(){
                console.log('Submited');
                //here will be a method for post request
            }
        },
  }
```

Comment: You have a typo there `post("/url\`, data)` The quotes dont match : `post("/url", data)`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the example below the fact that changing a variable in a promise trigger correctly the watcher.

I think that that your post is failing and thus not actually changing `isSubmited`.

You should catch the error.

```js
post("/url", data).then(response => {
  this.id_contract = response.data;
  this.isSubmited = !this.isSubmited;
}).catch(error => {
  console.log("post is failing")
});
```

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bool: false
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      this.bool = !this.bool;
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then(() => {
        this.bool = !this.bool;
      });
    }
  },
  watch: {
    bool: {
      handler() {
        console.log("CHANGE");
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="test">test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found out the problem. I had a router.push, that reset the value. And I fix it with a setTimeout, and place it at the end of the response.